# .on('click') doesn't work, but all other handlers do

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, triggers, click

I recently asked a question about triggering dynamically created divs, and was introduced to the .on() function.

'keyup' works great, 'mouseover' works, a few others I've tested work but 'click' just will not fire.

I created added information to a div via ajax and .php which holds some data like this:

```
function loadNewcomment(divID) {
$.ajax({
        url: templateUrl+"/enternote.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#"+divID).append(html);

        }
    });
}
```

I wanted to trigger on keyup for an element within that created div and this code works for that:

```
$("#notebox").on('keyup', '.note-field', function(event){
    var thisString = $(this).val();
    $keyLength = thisString.length;
    $rowCount = Math.ceil($keyLength/40);
    $currentRow = $(this).attr("rows");

    if($currentRow < $rowCount){
        $(this).animate({rows:$rowCount},50);
    }        

});
```

This code however does NOT work:

```
$("#notebox").on('click', '.note-field', function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: is `note-field` input field?

Comment: Can you show the associated HTML or perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: If `note-field` is an input, try using `focus`/`blur` instead of `click`, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: try changing `"#notebox"` to `document`

Comment: @SamuelCook That wouldn't change things if `keyup` works.

Comment: It is an input field... but It's actually not the element I want clicked, i'm just using it as an example because the element I want is a <span> right below it... it wasn't working so I tried it on the textarea to see if it would make a difference and It still won't work ... funny thing is, mouseover works, keyup, keydown, focus(on the textinput)... click is the only one not triggering.  Maybe something in my code is stoping clicks

Comment: I figured it out... i had a .stopPropagation(); somewhere ....

Answer (score 0):

dynamic DOM and jQuery is a pain.  I know its deprecated but I have used in the past with great results:  http://api.jquery.com/live/

FWIW - you could also try using bind() - http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: deprecated jquery 1.7 ... removed from 1.9

Comment: as stated, its deprecated but i've had instances in the past where on does not fire for dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had an .stopPropagation(); somewhere else in the code in the encompassing div, I commented it out for now and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to attach click event after html is appended.

```
function loadNewcomment(divID) {
$.ajax({
        url: templateUrl+"/enternote.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#"+divID).append(html).bind('click', function() { /* Click event code here */ }); // id divID is #notebox

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use click like this:

```
$("#notebox").click( function() {
  alert("clicked");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MBw4/

Comment: `dynamically created divs` == he can't.

Comment: he is creating a DOM element. the event won't trigger

Comment: This won't work... I'm actually looking for $('.note-field') to be clicked, but since it was created dynamically .click doesn't recognize it as being in the DOM.  .on should work fine, but it doesn't :/